# How do I call a JavaScript method from server side code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a call to client side code - on the server side, I'm going to spin off n-threads to do work

When each thread completes I'd like them to each individually callback a client-side function in order to append the result to an HTML table

Comment: you have 2 options: ajax polling or signalr

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling a javascript function in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445997/calling-a-javascript-function-in-c-sharp)

Comment: "I want to make a call to server side code" - What initiates this call, an AJAX request, or the browser requesting a URL?

Comment: An AJAX call will initiate the request from the client side

Comment: @blue18hutthutt - Then the server should return the HTML snippet in the AJAX response, and the javascript that initiated the AJAX call should add the result to the HTML table.  No need for the server to know anything about the HTML table.

Comment: @mbeckish - The problem with that approach is, if the server side code returns results at once like that, I won't get each update as the thread completes, rather I'm blocked until all threads complete, then returning the HTML back to the AJAX call that initiated it

Comment: What's wrong with the AJAX call blocking until the server is done?  The browser is still free to perform other actions.

Comment: Because I want to know as soon as a thread completes, when it completes. If a thread finishes in 2 seconds but the slowest thread takes 5min, I won't know until 5min later

Comment: Instead of 1 AJAX call that kicks off N server threads, you could kick off N AJAX calls that each spawn 1 server thread, and each waits synchronously until the response comes back.

Comment: Why are you using threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options: `ajax polling` or `signalr`

Check this out: http://bsmadhu.wordpress.com/2012/04/30/real-time-web-using-signalr/

Comment: as i'm sure you mean 'I think'