# Onclick statement doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension, and I'm trying to add a link that calls a javascript function, exactly [like in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265887/call-javascript-function-on-hyperlink-click).

However, when I click the link, nothing happens - and when I look at the debug console, the "a" node doesn't have an "onclick" property at all, it just looks like this:

```
<a href="#">Add to likes</a>
```

This is my code:

```
function generateEntry(innerEntry) {    
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("Add to likes");
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    a.onclick="addToLikes('" + "hello" + "')"
    a.href = "#";
    return a
}
```

If I manually add the "onclick" declaration in the debug console, everything works.

```
<a href="#" onclick="addToLikes('hello2')">Add to my likes</a>
```

What's wrong with my script?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the function for onclick

```
function generateEntry(innerEntry) {    
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("Add to likes");
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    //a.onClick="addToLikes('" + "hello" + "')"
    a.onclick = function () {
    addToLikes('hello2');
    };
    a.href = "#";
    return a
}
```

Comment: Perfect, you can put my answer how helpful's answer please

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` property takes a **function** as its value, not a string.

```
function addHelloToLikes() {
    addToLikes("hello");
}

a.onclick = addHelloToLikes;
```

You may wish to use, the more modern, [`addEventListener` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) instead.

Comment: I've copied it from google scholar results page - maybe it's something I don't get?: 
<a onclick="return gs_ocit(event,'Guq460GWSQ4J')" href="#" class="gs_nph">Cite</a>

Comment: @yossale — That's an HTML attribute, not a JavaScript property assignment.