# New to JQuery >> How can I have 2 <a> links and each one with a different function to execute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I apologize if this one will sound too easy for most, so I'm totally shooting an answer here:

Mainly I would like to understand how you bind different JQuery functions to different elements

==========================================
I have a MENU that has 2  links items

```
   <a id="aLogin" href="???">Login</a>
   <a id="aRegister" href="???">Register</a>
```

I also have 2 DIVs each one that shows the right elements

```
<div id="dLogin" class="hide">
  ...elements to login
</div>

<div id="dRegister" class="hide">
  ...elements to register
</div>
```

I understand that i can change the class from JQuery from "hide" to "show"
but my question is: **how can I specify the Login  link to execute the right Jquery function** (the one that changes the class of the DIV Login to "show") ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the href you just give `#`

```
<a id="aLogin" href="#">Login</a>
<a id="aRegister" href="#">Register</a>
```

Use the jQuery's [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event to bind onclick event to each link.
And the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle between the `hide` and `show` classes

```
$("#aLogin").click(function(){
    $("#dLogin").toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
    retun false;
}

$("#aRegister").click(function(){
    $("#dRegister").toggleClass("hide").toggleClass("show");
    retun false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#aLogin").click(function(){

//function to show or hide that div
$("#dLogin").toggle();
//or the function to show or hide div

}
```

Comment: So ...but i just put those 2 functions in the HTML page? What's the value of EACH href of the <a> link ?

Comment: You probably want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688196/how-to-use-a-link-to-call-javascript)