# How to clear Lookup field value in Visualforce page?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Once a lookup field is populated and I open the same visualforce page later then the lookup field is prepopulated.

I want to put 'X' next to Lookup field so that when 'X' is clicked, the field value gets cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a simple bit of javascript which sets the value of the field to blank, there's just a bit of Force.com magic regarding obtaining the ID of the element to use. Below is a complete page which does what you need.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputField id="accountLookup" value="{!Contact.AccountId}"/>
        <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('{!$Component.accountLookup}').value = ''; return false;">Clear</a>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Note** that [the recommended way of applying javascript to a link is to do it on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692954/481044), though you may find it simpler to do the above since it saves you having to drill down to the element `{!$Component.Parent.Child.Grandchild}` (which is needed when using `<apex:pageBlock>` etc.) and if javascript isn't enabled, your user will have bigger problems than your link not working!