# Call a function from a <a> tag in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I m creating a web application using object oriented javascript.I m having one class is having a function.
`var Section = function () { this.Test=function(){} }`.

From `<a href="#" />` i want to call the function `Test()`.

`<a href="#" onclick="new Section() Test()"/>`.

I m trying like this it was not working.

Is there any other option is there to call a function from control? Please suggest me.

Comment: `new Section().Test()`?

Comment: @putvande please write your comment as an answer so we can accept it as correct.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688196/how-to-use-a-link-to-call-javascript

Answer (score 2):

If you have a function or a variable inside an Object you have to use a `.` to access it. 
So in your case it should be :

```
var Section = function() {

    this.Test = function() {
        // Do something
    };
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="new Section().Test()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the javascript inside the href or inside the onClick attributes, like so:

```
<a href="javascript:var section = new Section(); section.Test();">
```

or

```
<a href="#" onClick="var section = new Section(); section.Test();">
```

Hope it helps, good luck!