# Javascript function not being run from click - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently making some accessibility options which make the font size increase or decrease on a page. Following EndangeredMassa's for [calling JS from a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688196/how-to-use-a-link-to-call-javascript) it appears not to work!

My current code (which is dummy code with the right IDs which will be used in my actual site), does not even run a Javascript alert, and since I'm not one for Javascript, if anyone could let me know what I'm doing wrong.

**HTML**

```
<p id="html">Nice to meet you!</p>
<a id="incFontS" href="#">Increase Text</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var incFont = document.getElementById("incFontS");
incFont.onClick = function () {
    window.alert("it ran!");
}
```

As you can see from my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhm4xzvg/), the code does not work at all, and I haven't even gotten to the part where I start changin the font sizes (geh!).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick

Comment: Also http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html is a very good read to learn more about event handling in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case matters in JavaScript. The correct property name is [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) (with a lowercase 'c'). Try this:

```
var incFont = document.getElementById("incFontS");
incFont.onclick = function () {
    window.alert("it ran!");
}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/rhm4xzvg/2/)

Also, be sure to read [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) for a discussion about different techniques for binding event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rhm4xzvg/3/)

```
var incFont = document.querySelector("#incFontS");
incFont.addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.alert("it ran!");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The function name is `onclick` not `onClick`

i.e.

```
var incFont = document.getElementById("incFontS");
incFont.onclick = function () {
    window.alert("it ran!");
}
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to do increase your font size

HTML CODE

```
<p id="html">Nice to meet you!</p>
<a id="incFontS" href="#" onclick="myFunction()">Increase Text</a>
```

Java Script Code

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("html").style.fontSize="xx-large";
}
</script>
```