# How to execute a script after a link is clicked, when browser does not support JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

I am trying to use Facebook conversion code like below that includes
both scripts and noscripts tags:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">

          // Wait for the page to load first
          window.onload = function() {

          //Get a reference to the link on the page
          // with an id of "mylink"
          var a = document.getElementById("mylink");

          //Set code to run when the link is clicked
          // by assigning a function to "onclick"
              a.onclick = function() {
                 // Code to be executed when the link is clicked.
                 var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
                 ...
              }
            }
          </script>
          <noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=6030151253043&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="mylink" href="http://example.com">Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Usually I can put this code in a thank you page in my website. But now I have a situation that I want to track if someone clicks an external link which leads to some external webpage that is out of my control. My page should not execute this conversion code when it loads but only when the link is clicked.

For example, my page has a link that goes to http://example.com, so when a user clicks this link, this conversion code can be executed and then go to http://example.com?

The problem is that when the browser does not support JavaScript, the code inside noscript tag will execute even if the link was not clicked.

Is there any way to solve that problem?

Comment: In Facebook conversion code, there is a <noscript> code, does it make any difference?

Comment: Code into a noscript tag is used when the script is not supported from the browser. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Comment: Consider Googling before posting a question. :)

Comment: So I can add <noscript>...</noscript> into a onClick function?

Comment: <noscript> is an HTML tag. You won't add it "into a onClick function". You can add it after the <script> tag.

Comment: When I say "after the <script> tag", of course I talk about the closing tag. xD

Comment: Sorry, based on the answer on the other question, my understanding is to execute the whole code inside onclick function. I am kind of confused now. The whole FB code (including <script> & <noscript> parts) has to be executed after a link is clicked.

Comment: The <noscript> tag follows the <script> tag and it will be only executed if the browser can't execute the main <script> tag or if it does not support JavaScript...

Comment: So maybe the answer does not address my specific question? Maybe there is actually some other solution? For example, the link should go to a php to execute the code and then redirect to the external link?

Comment: There is no difference. You will just add the <noscript> tag after the <script>.

Comment: If I add <noscript> after the <script> in my page, this code might get executed after my page is loaded but I just want the code to be executed after a link is clicked. Sorry, maybe I am missing something here.

Comment: Did you read the link I gave you? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Comment: "The <noscript> tag defines an alternate content for users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser that doesn't support script."

Comment: You dont really want this to be executed. Its just in case that the browser can't execute the normal script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94735/discussion-between-joe-and-kostas-lifeboy).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94736/discussion-between-kostas-lifeboy-and-joe).

Comment: please reopen this question, it's different than the other question.

Comment: @KostasLifeboy I wouldn't write a code like that when `<noscript>` is part of the Facebook code and ask a question in this way.

Comment: The only solution I can think right now, is to redirect the user to an empty page where the script executes any way and the redirect to the actual page.

Comment: Yes, I already implemented it this way and it works. However, my original question should be asked in my way because there are many other people who use FB conversion code should encounter similar situation, and I am looking for a best solution, not just a solution I came up with myself.

Comment: I saw at least one person actually rejected your edits with a very good reason. I really don't like the new way of asking this question. It's from a totally different perspective. I really don't care if a browser does not support Javascript when I cannot do it with onclick.

Comment: But anyway, to see a solution from this perspective is also ok. Thanks for your engagement & comments.

Comment: Well, if you would just ask how to run a script when a link is clicked, that would be a duplicate. But the <noscript> tag changes the situation, because it will run anyways when the page is loaded.

Comment: For this problem, there are two ways you can do it. The first is if you set the link as a POST sumbit of a hidden form and redirect the page, and the second solution, as I told above, would be to, instead of the original link, to set the link to a page especially for counting clicks on external links by running the <noscript> when that page loads or the normal script if the browser supports JavaScript. Then you can redirect to the page you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [JavaScript onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) event? For example:

```
var el; // This is your element pointing to the link you want to handle
el.onclick = function() {
    // Execute your code here, this event is fired before the default behaviour is executed which is to lead the user to the URL
};
```

If your el has an ID of mylink, then you can simply assign el as

```
var el = document.getElementById('mylink');
```

This code becomes even simpler to handle if you're using a JS library like jQuery but for the moment I'm assuming you're not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an edited version of the answer on [How to use a link to call JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688196/how-to-use-a-link-to-call-javascript)

```
        // Wait for the page to load first
        window.onload = function() {

          //Get a reference to the link on the page
          // with an id of "mylink"
          var a = document.getElementById("mylink");

          //Set code to run when the link is clicked
          // by assigning a function to "onclick"
          a.onclick = function() {

            // Your code here...

            //If you don't want the link to actually 
            // redirect the browser to another page,
            // "google.com" in our example here, then
            // return false at the end of this block.
            // Note that this also prevents event bubbling,
            // which is probably what we want here, but won't 
            // always be the case.
            return false;
          }
        }
    </script>
    <noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=6030151253043&amp;cd[value]=0.00&amp;cd[currency]=USD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="mylink" href="http://example.com">Link</a>        
</body>
</html>
```

[noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp) tag will be used only if the browser does not support JavaScript. And that's why you are not going to put any JavaScript there.

Comment: If a user who disables javascript and now opens my page, this <noscript> code will be executed and a conversion is tracked. I only want to track a conversion after a link is clicked. My page should not record any conversion.

Comment: That's why you will put your code into the "a.onclick = function() {}" event

Comment: Hmm... I got what you meant. Sec

Comment: A user who disables scripts opens this page will have <noscript> tag executed, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, because the script can't run.

Comment: then by opening this page, a conversion is tracked for this user who disable scripts. This is not a correct behavior. ... I just saw your earlier comment, do you get what I actually mean now?

Comment: Yes. I don't really know if you will be able to track the clicks with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Facebook will take care of it. What I really need to know is how to execute the whole conversion code (which includes <script> and <noscript>) after an external link is clicked. I really don't think this question is duplicate to the other question.

Comment: A solution for <noscript> would be using POST.

Comment: You can  also try changing the link to an another page that loads the <noscript> image and then redirects to the actual page.

Comment: You didn't have mention that difference before. ;-;

Comment: Yes, there must be some ways. That's why I asked this question in order to get the best solution because I am not that good in javascript/html/php.

Comment: I posted the Facebook conversion code in quite details in my question though.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can do it.

put in your link href="javascript:void(0)" and use javascript to redirect.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="do_and_redirect()">Your link</a>

<script>
function do_and_redirect(){
    //SOME CODE
    //..
    //..
    window.location.href = "http://yourpage.com";
}
</script>
```