# A href to link to javascript

Tags: javascript

Probably something simple so sorry!

Currently, I have `<button id="pin">Get pin</button>` and it works. (there is a script later on that this calls).

But, I want it to work on some text - preferable an `<a href>` as the styles are set up on this - so something like `<a href="pin">Get pin</a>` - obviously this would not work so would like to know how to get it to work! :)

I am trying to get it to run the below when clicking it:

```
<script>
    $("#pin").click(function() {
        swal("Your support pin", "Your support pin is: {$support_pin}", "info")
    });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that HTML in your question will be interpreted by our browsers *as HTML*, so you need to escape it as code by surrounding each HTML tag with backticks.

Comment: Question needs some code to clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can set up a click handler on a link as well, not just on a button.

Comment: It will work just fine -- though you'll need to prevent the default click handler with `e.preventDefault()`, `return false`, or similar.

Comment: I am trying to get it to do this: `<script>$("#pin").click(function() {
swal("Your support pin", "Your support pin is: {$support_pin}", "info")
});</script>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a link to call JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688196/how-to-use-a-link-to-call-javascript)

Comment: Someone blocked this question. So I have to comment answer. <a href="#" id="pin">Get pin</a> In your script will be like this; $("#pin").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); swal("Your support pin", "Your support pin is: {$support_pin}", "info") })

Comment: @bravemaster - not working either. I have put this:

`<li><a href="#" id="pin">Get pin</a></li>`

`<script>
    $("#pin").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); swal("Your support pin", "Your support pin is: {$support_pin}", "info") }) 
</script>`

Comment: Transform this question into chat. Then I'll help you solve that problem.

Comment: How do I do that @bravemaster?

Comment: Sorry, you don't have enough reputation. I'll upvote this question so that your reputation is over 20. Then you can join the chat room in this site. Or, this question has already too many comments so you will see the option here.

Comment: I'm not seeing the option for a chat. @bravemaster

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205557/discussion-between-tom-wilson-and-bravemaster).

Comment: @bravemaster here now

Answer (score 0):

Change href to "#" and add a click listener and it should work

```
<a href="#">Get pin</a>
```