# How to display a Pandas cell containing a clickable link to a local Python function?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, click

In a Jupyter notebook, how is it possible to display pandas cells displaying a clickable link allowing to trigger a call to a regular Python function?

For example, in the following dataframe, I would like to be able to manually click in a given row of the *Process* column to trigger the *process_item(item)* Python function:

```
   Item  Process
0  foo   click_here_to_process
1  bar   click_here_to_process

def process_item(item):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it can be done interactive way, but here is way you can store and call functions with in a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd

def hello(parameter): # Some custom function 
    print(parameter)
    return

variable = hello # assign the function to a variable
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': [variable,variable,variable,variable]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['col_2'][1]("hello World") #here we are calling the function with parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where each row in the dataframe has a clickable link which triggers a call to the regular python function `select_row`. The function is defined, currently, to set a global variable `selection` to the clicked row number, though the function can be defined differently.

To achieve this, the dataframe is embedded in custom html. I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688196/how-to-use-a-link-to-call-javascript) for help with the Javascript.

```py
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML as ipyhtml

# function for selecting a row
def select_row(row:'int'):
    global selection
    selection = row
    return
```

Defining the dataframe and interactivity in js + html

```py
# define the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(Name=['Mary', 'Bruce', 'Emma'], Score=[10,6,8]))

# add links as column into df, each with a unique id `mylink<row>`
# href = '#' does no redirecting in the browser
df['Select'] = [
    '<a id="mylink%s" href="#">Select</a>' % i for i in range(len(df))
]

# generate javascript <script>
js_script = """<script type="text/javascript">"""

for i in range(len(df)):
    js_script+="""
    
    // get a reference to each link "mylink<row>"
    
    var a%s = document.getElementById("mylink%s");
    
    // specify an "onclick" function for each link
    a%s.onclick = function() {
        // run the python function "select_row(<row>)"
        Jupyter.notebook.kernel.execute(`select_row(%s)`)
        return false;
      }
    """ % (i, i, i, i)
    
js_script+="""\n</script>"""


# generate the final html
selectable_df_html = """
    <html>
    <head>
    %s
    </head>
    <body>
    %s
    </body>
    </html>

""" % (js_script, df.style.to_html())
```

To display the df:

```py
ipyhtml(selectable_df_html)
```

Clicking any row's "Select" button will set the global variable `selection` to that row number

Comment: Could you clarify how your answer addresses the question asked? What can one do with the `selection` global variable?  Can one use your answer to "trigger a call to a regular Python function", as the OP wanted?